# Static IP device (10.0.0.xxx) left behind; network is now 192.168.1.xxx - what to do?

Tags: ip, lan, home-networking

A while back, I changed routers. The new router was configured to use 192.168.1.xxx for LAN addresses. Everything I had (I thought) was using DHCP, so I let everything grab a fresh 192.168.1.xxx address.

Now I realize I had one device on which I'd set a static IP in the 10.0.0.xxx range - a 2TB NAS.

For irrelevant reasons, I've been going through the router and assigning fixed IPs to several devices. I noticed the 10.0 NAS was still showing up (you can tell I don't use it much) in my list of connected devices.

I'm not too network-savvy, so is there a way I can get to it from my 192.168 network?

Answer (score 6):

Assign a static IP within 10.0.0.x range to your laptop/desktop. Connect to NAS device back-to-back without any intermediate device. Now you can able to access the NAS device. Change it to DHCP then connect back to router Network .